# How to dynamically render LWC Table Rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, table

I am unable to dynamically render table rows as a row using a child component.

### Parent:

```
<template>
        <template if:true={data.results}>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
        <template for:each={data.results} for:item="result">
            <c-child-table-row key={result.id} rowResult={result}></c-child-table-row>
        </template>
    </table>
    </template>
 </template>
```

### Child:

```
<template>
    <tr key={rowResult.id}>
        <td>
            {rowResult.id}
        </td>
    </tr>   
</template>
```

The rows rendered are not rendered as a table even though inspecting the DOM shows they have the appropriate classes.

Comment: Because LWC uses Shadow DOM you need to be a bit explicit with the CSS. Try adding, in the CSS for Child: `:host { display: table-row }`. If that works (a variant on this theme did for us), I'll convert this to an answer.

Comment: yep - this is what i had to do in the past - no other way. if you are using aura attributes as well add them to the component level as well.

Comment: also the tr tag can likely be pulled out as the :host is treated as such

Comment: @PhilW, I couldn't get it with the :host CSS above, but this was the problem. As stated in the documentation: "CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child"

Comment: We have successfully done this using `:host { display: xxx }`. TBH, we used `table-header-group` for what we were doing (the child was a header row). You could try various other display options if `table-row` isn't working for you. Alternatively, move the `<tr>` into the parent and have the child simply render a sequence of `td` elements? Or as Ronnie said, simply remove the `<tr>` from the child template since the outer-most `<template>` is what is being treated as a row via the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWC uses Shadow DOM and custom elements. You are wanting to generate a structure like:

```
<table> <!-- from parent -->
  <tr><td>X</td></tr> <!-- from child -->
...
```

However, what you actually get is something like:

```
<table> <!-- from parent -->
  <c-child> <!-- from parent -->
    <tr><td>X</td></tr> <!-- from child -->
  </c-child> <!-- from parent --> 
...
```

To handle this:

1. Add CSS to the child of the form: `:host { display: table-row }`
2. Remove the `tr` tag from the child, since the above CSS means that the `c-child` element is treated like a TR (because this is what is actually included in the DOM in place of the outer-most `template` element in the child LWC's template).

This will result in markup of the form:

```
<table> <!-- from parent -->
  <c-child> <!-- from parent -->
    <td>X</td> <!-- from child -->
  </c-child> <!-- from parent --> 
...
```

with the `c-child` element being treated as if it were a `tr`, due to the child's CSS, so *effectively*:

```
<table> <!-- from parent -->
  <tr> <!-- "from" child due to CSS -->
    <td>X</td> <!-- from child -->
  </tr> <!-- "from" child due to CSS --> 
...
```

(I have ignored `key` values and looping you'll need for iteration)